# Image and text isnt aligned perfectly

Tags: html, css, alignment

I always have the problem that when I align an image and some text side by side that the text is 1-2px under the image so it doesnt look perfectly aligned.

```
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p style="float:left; margin-right:20px; margin-bottom:20px; margin-top:0px;"><img    src="http://public.media.smithsonianmag.com/legacy_blog/npg_portraits_nicholson_jack_2002.jpg" style="width:200px;"></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
```

Also made a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/emdu77z3/

Mostly I give the image margin-top:1px or something like that but whats the reason for that? Is there a better solution?

Comment: It has to do with the line-height. Reducing the line-height will "fix" it but will also influence all other lines what messes everything up so you will be left with either giving the img a positiv margin or the text a negative margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you mean. At the top the image is always higher than the text. A simple fix would be to add a margin-top to the image. It's not good practice to put the styles inline, so I made it a class.

http://jsfiddle.net/emdu77z3/2/

I changed the `<p>` to `<p class="block">` and gave it a css rule:

```
/*Selects all images within the class "block" */
.block img {
    margin-top:3px;   
}
```